# Understand tflite interpreter output and map it to probabilties of classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have trained an ssd model (for object detection) using a pre-trained SSD model from Google and converted it to tflite. I trained it for 10 classes and convert it to tflite.
Below is the code that I used to call converted tflite model to inspect the results

```
import tensorflow as tf
MODEL_PATH = 'tflite_model_path'
IMAGE_PATH = 'image of .jpeg or .png format'

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=MODEL_PATH)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)  
image_np = np.array(img)
resized_image = tf.image.resize(image_np, [320, 320])
input_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(resized_image, 0), dtype=tf.uint8)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

print(output_data)
[[0.05507272 0.6531384  0.94264597 1.0628431 ]
[0.09443301 0.23600875 0.86310023 0.59367293]
[0.28634408 0.27470273 0.8326082  0.4465307 ]
[0.04376397 0.27534395 0.92427313 0.9200937 ]
[0.00423892 0.824869   0.09153695 0.9980754 ]
[0.63915586 0.6903409  0.9311851  0.97774005]
[0.11331517 0.25821632 0.67732155 0.4566245 ]
[0.4935118  0.27333832 0.82703865 0.4118209 ]
[0.04359788 0.68944013 0.39454672 1.0057622 ]
[0.3145248  0.13302818 1.0334518  0.9483361 ]]]
```

Now when calling my tflite model using a tflite interpreter, a few things are not clear to me:

1. What `output_details` is returning?
2. Shape of `output_details` is `tf.Tensor([ 1 10  4], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)`. What does this shape and these numbers represent?
3. How to convert this output to the prob corresponding to each class?

Comment: Is this model for object detection? What have you trained it for?

Comment: Yes this is for object detection. I trained it for 10 objects

Comment: So I presume that they are the coordinates for each object the model identifies. You have to see the original model and how these coordinates are transformed to a rect with left,top, right, bottom values.

Comment: You might. be correct but how to get probabilities of each object then?

Comment: There is a possibility that output_data contains also other information, other arrays that do not get printed by doing print(output_data). View your tflite file with netron.app to see the outputs and try also print(output_data[0]), print(ouput_data[1])... to see if there are more info.